# Openstack Junos rapid production deployment

Tags: openstack

Can somebody familiar with Open Stack explain to me whether or not it's ok to use the RDO version for production use. The installation takes a matter of minutes compare to the doc installation Guide. I have installed Open stack in the past on multiple VM and now I'm trying to build a rapid deployment platform in Python, that will automated the open stack installation for production use. If there's already a Rapid deployment software can someone guide me in the right path.

Comment: Look at PackStack and the existing puppet modules. Don't try to reinvent the wheel, especially not a very large complex one like this.

Comment: I was told that Packstack should only be used for testing purposes not for production use.

Comment: Who told you that, and why?

Comment: A friend of mine. So i would go ahead and start familiarizing myself with Pack Stack. installing it and configuruing untill i master it. And t hen i can start running python scripts to further ease the installation process.

Comment: So is there's a difference between RDO and Packstack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use RDO in production. Whether or not that's OK is a judgement call that depends on site-specific factors (use cases, SLAs, culture, etc) that you may know but I certainly don't. It is certainly *not* the case that RDO is fundamentally broken in some way which prevents its use in production, and even if it were, you should simply fix those bugs :-)

Regarding deployment tools, have a look at The Foreman too. Also, I would not recommend that you write Python code to install OpenStack. If the existing Puppet manifests inside Packstack aren't sufficient, I'd recommend writing more Puppet, or stealing Packstack's Puppet manifests, modifying them, then using them without Packstack, or forget about Packstack entirely and just use the upstream Puppet modules from stackforge/puppetforge/wherever.

In reply to your comment, yes, there is a difference between RDO and Packstack. RDO is a distribution of OpenStack, whereas Packstack is a tool for installing OpenStack.

Comment: Any good RDO tutorial that you personally recommend. I want to build a web based Openstack installation, In order to make the installation non technical.

Comment: The Foreman aims to do this, and succeeds quite well in my opinion. I think you'd probably be better off using/enhancing Foreman, than re-creating it from scratch.

Here's a good RDO+Foreman tutorial:
https://openstack.redhat.com/Deploying_RDO_using_Foreman

The same site has good RDO+Packstac tutorials too, but I suspect that Foreman would be better than Packstack for your purposes.

Hope this helps! :-)